# My settings wont open there's no option to open it in the apps DellComp

Tags: 20.04, dell, settings

My settings wont open there's no option to open it in the apps menu,on the top right corner the settings icon i click on and nothing happens. DellComp

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the top left corner? Something should say "Activities"

Click on it and you should see a bubble in the top center of the screen (with a hint that says type to search).

Type settings there and you should be able to access the Settings for your machine.